# Expresso Store: Send Email X days after purchase

Tags: expresso-store, email, expresso

My client has requested that the site automatically sends users an email X days after their initial purchase.

Whilst I can probably work out some custom DB queries to get customers who had brought stuff X days ago are there any hooks I can use to trigger Expresso Store to send one if its own templates out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

A list of Expresso Store hooks can be found in their documentation here:
https://exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html

I don't see a hook that does what you're asking. But you can build something on your own using the EE Email Class as detailed here:
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/email.html

Comment: Thanks Anna_MediaGirl. We've actually integrated with the Mailchimp API and are using their scheduling tools for this purpose. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built-in. You could as Anna mentioned build an extension that would allow to send it. There area  few ways you could approach this, I have seen in the past an extension that changes the order status which triggers an email based upon the assigned status.

Alternatively you could use Objective HTML's [PostMaster](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster) add-on. You would need to setup a parcel based upon the rules you want to trigger an email. Once the rule is triggered it will send the email out, the nice thing about this is that you can configure multiple parcels to send out multiple emails or different emails based upon what the user purchased.

The other option and an option that I see a lot of people use is to sign the user up to a MailChimp or CampaignMonitor list that will send out emails a set amount of days from being added to the list. This can be super handy if you have multiple emails that need to be sent out at certain times. The downside to this is that it is not as easy to pull in the purchased items to the email body.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your reply. The extension that changes the order status sounds interesting. Can you remember what its called please?

Comment: The extensions that I have seen in the past that have similar functionality were not publicly released as far as I am aware.

Comment: Thanks Justin. We've actually integrated with the Mailchimp API and are using their scheduling tools for this purpose. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Objective HTML [Postmaster](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster) add-on takes care of all of your emails regardless of the condition! I strongly recommend using this add-on! Read the documentation and see for yourself..

Comment: Thanks heinkasner. We've actually integrated with the Mailchimp API and are using their scheduling tools for this purpose. Thanks for the suggestion though.